# unable to write file to database

Tags: database, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, pentaho-cde

I have a file that I received via FTP. This file needs to be placed in PostgreSQL. How to do it? I tried to do it with "Bulk load into MySQL", I selected the desired database, but the file could not be written. Help me please.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnLmr.png)

[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5lcV.png)

P.S.the test connection is successful

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The Bulk load into MySQL can only be used with MySQL, not Postgres. There’s a Postgres bulk loader too, I believe. Failing that you will need to read the file with a Text file input in a transformation and load it using the Table output step.